# Issuer certificate is invalid

Tags: linux, ssl, curl, apache-nifi

I want to user rest api in secure nifi  ,but after  trying  this  curl command:
`curl --verbose related  url` i  got  this  error:

> Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA certificates
>   curl: (60) Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with known CA
>   certificates

i  have self  signed  certificate and  after  trying  this  curl command:

```
curl -k --verbose related  url and  even  after  trusting certificate  by  curl- k  command  i got  exception like this:
```

> NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
>   what  should i change in my  certificate to get  rid of this exception?
>   Here are  several subjects  i am interested in:

Can  you  recommend  some  other  curl commands  which  can  help me debug  connection  with rest api (in secure nifi).